# Авторизация на сайте при помощи Steam Web API

Tags: php, steam-web-api, steam

Возникла неизвестная проблема, которую я не могу найти.
Делаю авторизацию с помощью Steam Web API ([подробнее](http://habrahabr.ru/post/172223/)).
Есть ссылка:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$STEAMAPI&steamids=$matches[1]
```

где `$STEAMAPI` — переменная с ключом;
 `$matches[1]` — переменная, значение которой будет после авторизации в Steam, `steamid`.

По этим данным в формате JSON будет выводится информация об аккаунте Steam. Почему-то с помощью функций `file_get_contents`, `json_decode` не удается вывести информацию об аккаунте. Например, есть информация —

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=98798566D0A8DA0C305F49760266BBF4&steamids=76561198039950522
```

Как видим, тут данные приведены на примере. Сам код для вывода этой информации:

```
 $url = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$STEAMAPI&steamids=$matches[1]");
    $data = (array) json_decode($url)->response->player[0];             
    print_r($data);
```

Все переменные, которые входят в ссылку, не пустые, и я их проверял — всё отлично.
Но почему-то массив пустой оказывается.

Код полностью:

```
<?php
require 'openid/openid.php';
$STEAMAPI = "98798566D0A8DA0C305F49760266BBF4";
try 
{
    $openid = new LightOpenID('http://steam-tests2.hol.es/register.php');
    if(!$openid->mode) 
    {
        if(isset($_GET['login'])) 
        {
            $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid/?l=english'; 
            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
        }
?>
<form action="?login" method="post">
    <input type="image" src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_small.png">
</form>
<?php
    } 
    elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') 
    {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
    } 
    else 
    {
        if($openid->validate()) 
        {
                $id = $openid->identity;
                // identity is something like: http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/76561197960435530
                // we only care about the unique account ID at the end of the URL.
                $ptn = "/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
                preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);
                echo "User is logged in (steamID: $matches[1])\n";
                $url = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$STEAMAPI&steamids=$matches[1]");
                $data = (array) json_decode($url)->response->player[0];

                print_r($data);
        } 
        else 
        {
                echo "User is not logged in.\n";
        }
    }
} 
catch(ErrorException $e) 
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, тому посту уже как год, а во-вторых, я думаю, вам лучше начать с реализации архитектуры вашего сайта, реализовать для начала MVC или HMVS, а не все в куче, а потом уже переходить к таким вещам.

Насколько мне известно, OpenID стима работает только по защищенному протоколу, то бишь HTTPS, а у вас по обычному.

Comment: Это не та проблема, стим будет работать и с обычным протоколом HTTTP. И все равно я поправил протокол, все равно результат не меняется.